# How can I make my state.expirationDate triggers in real time?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm using hydrated bloc and I want to make that my expirationDate attribute will change in real time when the time expires, but I only can do it making a hot reload

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // Constructor
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: BlocBuilder<SessionBloc, SessionState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          switch (state.expirationDate?.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
            case true:
              return const LoginBuilder();
            case false:
              return const RoleScreensBuilder();
            default:
              return const LoginBuilder();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my state:

```
@immutable
class SessionState extends Equatable {
  // Constructor
  const SessionState({
    this.expirationDate,
    this.isExpired = true,
  });

  // Attributes
  final DateTime? expirationDate;
  final bool isExpired;
```

I'm already saw the Stream Subscription documentation  but I don't know how to do it and if is the best implementation

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making your comparison to the current time in the bloc class and not the UI. Then that `BlocBuilder` would only care if `isExpired` is true or not. I don't know what your bloc class looks like, but this should give you the right idea.

```
class SessionBloc extends HydratedBloc<SessionEvent, SessionState> {
  SessionBloc() : super(const SessionState()) {
    // call this when you initialize the bloc
    on<InitExpirationListener>(_onInitExpirationListener);
  }
  // Updates the current time every second
  static final Stream<DateTime> _timer = Stream<DateTime>.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 1), (count) => DateTime.now());

  Future<void> _onInitExpirationListener(
    InitExpirationListener event,
    Emitter<SessionState> emit,
  ) async {
    // emit.forEach is the preferred way to listen to streams with Bloc
    await emit.forEach(
      _timer,
      onData: (DateTime currentTime) { // gets updated every second
        print(currentTime); // prints every second
        // make your comparison to stored expiration here and update the
        // bool accordingly. If no update is required, `return state;`
        ...
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then your `BlocBuilder` logic gets simplified to

```
...
return state.isExpired ? LoginBuilder() : RoleScreensBuilder();
```